# Get subtotal, apply discount, and show new amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below but I'm having issues when the dollar amount has commas, for example $1,234.56. When I use the code below, it spits out 0.00. It should show the new subtotal with comma(s) if it's over a thousand.

```
var subtotal = $('.divWithAmount').text().replace("$",""); // Get the subtotal amount and remove the dollar sign
var discount = subtotal * 0.2; // Multiply the amount by 20%
var newSub = subtotal - discount; // Calculate the new subtotal
var newSubtotal = newSub.toFixed(2); // Show only the last two numbers after the decimal
console.log(newSubtotal);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try it with removing the $ and commas?

Comment: I did try LGson suggestion below but it would great if I can add back the comma(s) if the value of newSubtotal is more than a thousand.

Comment: I suggest you try newer way of doing thing using Number type and with the help of regular expression...

Comment: parseFloat("123456789012345.229") will return 123456789012345.23
     parseFloat("123456789012345.203") will return 123456789012345.2 .. so ti snot consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason it doesn't work is that the returned value from `$('.divWithAmount').text()` is of type `String`

To do operations it needs to be a number, and to enable that you also need to remove the comma and then parse it with e.g. `parseFloat()`.

```js
var subtotal = parseFloat($('div').text().replace("$","").replace(",",""));
var discount = subtotal * 0.2; // Multiply the amount by 20%
var newSub = subtotal - discount; // Calculate the new subtotal
var newSubtotal = newSub.toFixed(2); // Show only the last two numbers after the decimal
console.log(parseFloat(newSubtotal).toLocaleString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>$51,234.56</div>
```

---

*As commented, I updated my answer with `toLocaleString`, so the comma gets added back.*

*Here is a couple of ways how to localize the end result:*

*- [Javascript Thousand Separator / string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format/3753507#3753507)*

*- [Add thousands separator to auto sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502333/add-thousands-separator-to-auto-sum?rq=1)*

*- [convert a JavaScript string variable to decimal/money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095795/convert-a-javascript-string-variable-to-decimal-money)*

Comment: LGSon, if the amount in the div is, as an example, $80,234.56, the new amount for newSubtotal is 64187.65. Is there something that needs to be updated so the comma is added back ($64,187.65)?

Comment: @user2428993, for adding the commas, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753507/4770813), apparently there is a built in function for this

Comment: @user2428993 Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

to get number out of string value just do like this

```
var amount = "$1,234.56";
var doublenumber = Number(amount.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```

once you get number then you can perform operation you want and it will resolve your issue that you are facing.