# Jquery number format

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

I have a script like this, for shipping options

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    var total = 0;
    function calcTotal()
    {
        $("input:checked").each(function()
        {
            //This happens for each checked input field
            var value = $(this).attr("value");
            total += parseInt(value);           

        });
    }
    //This happens when the page loads
    calcTotal();    
    $("#total").append('<input style="border:0px" type="text" name="total" value=" '+ total +' " readonly />');
    $("input:radio").click(function()
    {
        total = 0;
        calcTotal();
        $("#total").html ('<input style="border:0px" type="text" name="total" value=" '+ total +' " readonly />');
    });
});
</script>
```

using the radio inputs to the option results in total

option 1 `<input name="shipp" type="radio" value="1234567" checked />`

option 2 `<input name="shipp" type="radio" value="2345678" />`

output: `<div id=total></div>`

I need help, how to make the view the total number of formats for thousands?, for example **1234567**, the result will be **1,234,567** ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of:

[Add comma to numbers every three digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-using-jquery)

From Doug Neiner's answer on thread:

> @Paul Creasey had the simplest solution as the regex, but here it is
>   as a simple jQuery plugin:
>
> $.fn.digits = function(){ 
>       return this.each(function(){ 
>           $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") ); 
>       }) }
>
> You could then use it like this:
>
> $("span.numbers").digits();

Please Up his answer.

Your Solution would look like:
...

```
    $("input:checked").each(function()
    {
        //This happens for each checked input field
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        total += parseInt(value.replace(",",""));           

    });

    //This happens when the page loads
    calcTotal();   
    var totalAsString = total.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");  
    $("#total").append('<input style="border:0px" type="text" name="total" value=" '+ totalAsString +' " readonly />');
    $("input:radio").click(function()
    {
        total = 0;
        calcTotal();
        $("#total").html ('<input style="border:0px" type="text" name="total" value=" '+ totalAsString +' " readonly />');
    });
```

Comment: Hallo @ Doug Neiner's.
maybe you can help me how do I add a script that you gave into my script above so that it can work. I really still can.
thank you

Comment: I have put up version 1.1 of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`intVariable.toLocaleString()` does everything for you