# Unwanted comma in XHR response ending up in table's cells

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, datatables, xmlhttprequest

I have an XHR response that looks something like this:

```
[
    [
        "e33222",
        "1730-06-27",
        "Lewis Morris",
        [
            "Edward Wynne; ",
            "William Bulkeley"
        ]
    ], [...]
]
```

It is used to populate a table with

```
var table = $('#mainTable').DataTable()
table.rows.add(result)
table.draw();
```

It all works great, except for an annoying comma added at the beginning of every subsequent sub-item (or, better, at the end of every first sub-item which has a following one, see "Edward Wynne; ", "William Bulkeley").

The end result is that in the cell corresponding to that data I get:

```
William Morris; ,Richard Morris
```

Is there any way of getting:

```
William Morris; Richard Morris
```

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commas and $ in datatable columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280817/commas-and-in-datatable-columns)

Comment: You can process the data so it is the way you want before you add it.

Comment: The "render" : function would need to be called when the table is initialised. My need is to format the data after a XHR call, which clears and repopulates the table. Can I call the 'render' after the draw() function?

Comment: @epascarello This is a JSON respnse, and the comma is outside the actual data coming from the XHR, so to speak (i.e. outside the inverted commas). How can I prevent JSON not to have commas between fields?

Comment: Because it is doing toString() on an array in your datatable, so process it so it is not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So loop over the data before you set it in the datatable and format the data so it is not an array.

```js
var results = [
    [
        "e33222",
        "1730-06-27",
        "Lewis Morris",
        [
            "Edward Wynne; ",
            "William Bulkeley"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "22222",
        "2222-06-27",
        "foooo Mooooo",
        [
            "foo bar; ",
            "foo baz"
        ]
    ],    
]

results.forEach(function (record) {
  record[3] = record[3].join('')
})
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, and it works in your snippet. Nevertheless I get 'TypeError: record[3].join is not a function' when I run it in my webiste. I should add that not all the records have sub-items, many record only have one item. could this be an issue?

Comment: I do not know what your data is so hard to know, just went off what you shown us.