# jquery removing comma and incrementing by 1?

Tags: jquery

I have a span element which holds a number such as `1,568`.

When a button is clicked, I need that number to increment by 1.  So `1,568` becomes `1,569`.

If I just get the value and add `+ 1` to it, the value becomes `2`:

```
("#artist-fan-count").text(parseInt($("#artist-fan-count").text()) + 1);
```

Should I try to remove the comma and then run the code above?  If I do the line below, nothing happens -- which leads me to believe I'm doing it wrong.  Shrug.

```
$("#artist-fan-count").text().replace(',', '');
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove all the commas, parseInt, increment, and then reconstruct your number with the commas, like so:

```
var $e = $("#artist-fan-count");
var num = parseInt($e.text().replace(',','')) + 1;
$e.text($.fn.digits(num));
```

using digits from:
[Add comma to numbers every three digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-using-jquery)

Comment: There we go. Everything from the other four answers wrapped into one ;)

Comment: yep, each answer was slightly off, and by combining them all, you get the whole store ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following to remove the comma and increment by 1:

```
var fanCountEl = document.getElementById('artist-fan-count');
fanCountEl.innerHTML = parseInt(fanCountEl.innerHTML.replace(',', '')) + 1;
```

Comment: this won't put the comma back.

Comment: This works great.  is there a php number_format equivalent I can use to put the comma back?

Comment: Indeed, it won't. You'll have to add the comma back separately using another function.

Comment: @Mike - I believe jQuery has a number format extension you can install. You could also take a look at [this article](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html) with working code examples for an "addCommas"-style function

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to write your replaced text back:

```
$("#artist-fan-count").text($("#artist-fan-count").text().replace(',', ''));
```

after that, you can parse your text as an integer, add your number and (if you want to) put that comma back in place.

If you want to reassemble your Text:

```
var number = $("#artist-fan-count").text();
$("#artist-fan-count").text(parseInt(number/1000)+","+(number%1000));
```

Comment: This is... The same as my answer?

Comment: hmm, seems that i just have slower Internet-Connection ;-) But yes, the point of that answer seems to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that :

```
var $e = $("#artist-fan-count");
var str = ''+(parseInt($e.text().replace(/,/g,''), 10)+1);
var r = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
while (r.test(str))  str = str.replace(r, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
$e.text(str);
```

Comment: this will fail for 2,999, it will display 2,1000 instead of 3,000.

Comment: @MohamedNuur I thought this was the goal.

Comment: @MohamedNuur If I get the goal (see the whole as a number), so this should do it.

Comment: think about it like this: it's like he's displaying money: `$1,762.34` and he needs to add some amount to it and re-format it. that's how i saw it.

Comment: @MohamedNuur Yes, I see it now, I'm just not used to those American numbers. I think my new code is correct.

Comment: in the question, he mentions that he has a number `1,568` and he wants to increment it by 1. Not two numbers and he only wants to increment the second number by 1.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but replace doesn't do it in-place:

```
$("#artist-fan-count").text($("#artist-fan-count").text().replace(',', ''));
```