# Asp.net mvc 4 format thousand separator for textbox with jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 1 model as follows:

```
 Product: 
    public int id
    public int price
```

in my view i want use jquery auto format thousand separator for text box price when user input price ( i want format immediately when user input)

```
example: when user input
123 -> 123
4567 -> 4,567
45678 -> 45,678
456 -> 456
```

sorry my english not good
thanks so much!

Comment: I would use jQuery plugins for  things like that

Comment: Here's something to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-using-jquery  This one does not appear to operate on a control during input, but it should be easy enough to adapt.  Hope that helps.  EDIT: one of the comments in the accepted answer has another person's attempt at using the algorithm for an input control.  Good luck.