# Angularjs decimal separator comma

Tags: angularjs, input, internationalization

I am fighting to get i18n working with a number input. I want the user to input "," as decimal separator when language is danish.

In the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/WTPV8o9pJLjY4onjBEgW I have included danish i18n file.
In chrome it allows both "," and "." as decimal separator.
In firefox and IE it still only allows ".".

Am I missing something? :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767262/angular-js-wrapping-the-currency-symbol-and-decimal-numbers-in-spans

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28737885/185655

Comment: use the following module.. http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-input-decimal-separator

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to support legacy browsers without HTML5 support, you can use [`<input type="number" />`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) to get a correct validation against the browser's locale setting.