# Replace comma with a dot in input field

Tags: angularjs

European countries uses a comma-sign (,) instead of a dot (.) when they enter decimal numbers. So I want to replace the dot sign with a comma when users enter input. I'm aware that input=number do this but I need support for IE.

I guess directive is the best to do this? I gave it a try with the code below. But it fails.

```
  .directive('replaceComma', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
          var convert = String(v).replace(",",".");
          attrs.NgModel = convert;
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

The convert variable is correct. But the value does not change in the input box. So I guess attrs.ngModel = convert, is wrong?

Comment: I guess you want to replace a `dot` with `comma` not `comma` with `dot`

Comment: Here's a [directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/pKXX2xcNjxmrdgtqVh2c?p=preview) to do that.

Comment: The following module may solve your issue.. http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-input-decimal-separator

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no need to do this like a directive.

say your template is

```
<input ng-model='someModel'>
```

in your controller,

```
$scope.$watch('someModel',function(newVal){
    $scope.someModel = newVal.replace(/,/g,'.');
})
```

ng-model is a two-way binding, so it should work

Comment: Tried this and it also worked. But a directive is better since it keeps your controller more clean.

Answer (score 2):

## **Via directive:**

```
.directive('replacecomma', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newVal) {
                if (newVal !== undefined && newVal !== null) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(String(newVal).replace(/,/g, '.'));
                    element.val(String(newVal).replace(/,/g, '.'));
                }
            })

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

var mystring = "this,is,a,test"
mystring = mystring.split(',').join(' ');

mystring contain ==> "this is a test"

Answer (score 1):

In your template:

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="someModel" replace-comma >
```

in your module :

```
.directive('replaceComma', function(){
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
        function fromUser(text) {
            if (text) {
                var transformedInput = text.replace(/,/g, '.')
                if (transformedInput !== text) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            }
            return undefined;
        }
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
};});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, but I think `directive` is attached to module not controller.