# Data attribute, separate by commas

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing a website using html, css, jQuery.

I am trying to show some stats that will be kind of numbers say: 376766 user registered

But I am doing it by `data-` attribute:

```
<strong class="datafill1" data-to="">0</strong>
```

Here I pass `data-to` by a random script generator.

Problem is that I want to separate numbers by comma but I am not able to do

Please help me

- Current Format :376766
- Desired Format : 3,76,766

I am trying it but not able to do it :(

Update :
Here is the script:
//-------------------------fake counter 1

```
function fakecounter1(){

//decrease/increase counter value (depending on perceived popularity of your site!)
var decrease_increase=11439

var counterdate=new Date()
var currenthits=counterdate.getTime().toString()
currenthits=parseInt(currenthits.substring(2,currenthits.length-4))+decrease_increase

var df1=currenthits -2746740;
$('.datafill1').attr('data-to', df1);
}
fakecounter1()
```

Comment: Can we see the said-`random script generator`?

Comment: You can pass any string to a data-attribute but you cannot adjust the number pattern with CSS once it's in there...at least as far as I know.

Comment: @Paulie_D please have a look on updated que.

Comment: I think you 'd need to do some initial parsing to break the number up before passing that string to the attribute. There are plugins to do that. or pure JS - http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html

Comment: here is live link http://sigrideducation.com/btpwebsitenew/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add comma to numbers every three digits using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking but I think you want to get a number printed with commas as thousands separators (which according to your Desired Format example is *not* what you want but I am assuming a typo.)

JavaScript code to display an *integer* with commas:

```
var d = 1234567;
var s = (''+d).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/g, "$1,"); // 1,234,567
```

The result is obviously a string.