# comma separated values in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, uiculture

I am trying to get the comma separated values .. here is my UI code

```
 <table id="dtreport" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-response">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        if (col.ColumnName != "PackageDataID")
                        {
                        <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                    }
                }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            if (col.ColumnName != "PackageDataID")
                            {
                                if (col.ColumnName == "IPC" || col.ColumnName == "From Date" || col.ColumnName == "To Date")
                                {
                            <td style="text-align: center">@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            <td style="text-align: right">@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

i am trying to set the globalization in body, as i have seen this format in google search....
i set my globalization in web.config as

```
 <globalization uiCulture="hi" culture="hi-IN" />
```

but the output was not as expected.. please have a look into the image..
[image: output when i add the globalization.currentculture in body of table]

Answer (score 0):

you can define simple [Extension Method](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjavsn69N_JAhVLVRQKHQudCq8QFgguMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen%2Flibrary%2Fbb383977.aspx&usg=AFQjCNFr5J27dmpLmNChIpvG3vZgrsluEA&bvm=bv.110151844,d.bGQ) to do this for you. then call it in 
razor. only you need to use `namesapace` of extension method

```
 public static string separate(this string value)
    {
        // you need additional code to find digit value to separate them. then pass it to regex method.
        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(value, ".{3}", "$0,");
    }
```

in razor

```
@row[col.ColumnName].tostring().separate()
```

*also you can use javascript and jquery [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-using-jquery)