# Ag-Grid: Number Formatting eg:123456.78 to 123,457

Tags: ag-grid

I have huge sets of numeric data.
this needs to be rendered as comma separated value.
For Ex. 
`123456.78` to be rendered as `123,457` using Ag-Grid.
Kindly help me on achieving this.

Comment: check this, i guess it will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits

Comment: Thanks for your response,
    we have **cellFilter:'number:"":0'** in ui-grid of angular js. So, it would be helpful, finding some builtin function available in Ag-Grid.

Answer (score 20):

As per the cell rendering flow documentation ([here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering)), you can use the colDef.valueFormatter, like this:

```js
    var columnDefs = [
        {headerName: "Number", field: "number"},
        {headerName: "Formatted", field: "number", valueFormatter: currencyFormatter}
    ];
    
    function currencyFormatter(params) {
        return '£' + formatNumber(params.value);
    }
    
    function formatNumber(number) {
        // this puts commas into the number eg 1000 goes to 1,000,
        // i pulled this from stack overflow, i have no idea how it works
        return Math.floor(number).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
```

You could also use a cellRenderer as other posts describe, but that's typically for more complex rendering, whereas the valueFormatter is specifically for this case. From the ag-grid [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters):

> valueFormatter's are for text formatting.
> cellRenderer's are for when you want to include HTML markup and
> potentially functionality to the cell. So for example, if you want to
> put punctuation into a value, use a valueFormatter, if you want to put
> buttons or HTML links use a cellRenderer. It is possible to use a
> combination of both, in which case the result of the valueFormatter
> will be passed to the cellRenderer.

Comment: `currencyFormatter(params: any) {
    return Math.floor(params.value)
      .toString()
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
  }`
If you want to do it in React Ts

Answer (score 17):

```
{
         headerName: 'Salary', field: 'sal'
        cellRenderer: this.CurrencyCellRenderer
       }

private CurrencyCellRenderer(params:any) {

    var usdFormate = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD',
        minimumFractionDigits: 4
    });
    return usdFormate.format(params.value);
}
```

Like these we can mention in Angular2 Typescript code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Excellent response, the one I needed

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by writing a "customcellRenderer", when you create a column definition provide a function to "cellRenderer " attribute and in renderer use number filter, something like this

```
var colDef = {
    name: 'Col Name',
    field' 'Col Field',
    cellRenderer: function(params) {
        var eCell = document.createElement('span');
        var number;
        if (!param.value || !isFinite(param.value)) {
            number = '';
        } else {
            number = $filter('number')(param.value, 0);
        }
        eCell.innerHTML = number;
        return eCell;
    }
}
```

Comment: there are value formatting functions such as valueFormatted. aren't those there to accomplish this? seems crazy to have to provide entire rendering function every time you want to format a string