# Currency Format in ag-grid using angular 2 latest version

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm displaying currency calculations in my ag-grid project but i'm trying to set the currency value in a US currency format (like 232,345). I have no idea how to set that in ag-grid can anyone please help to resolve my issue.

I tried coding like these:

```
{
     cellRendererFramework: { template: '{{params.firstSalary | currency}}'},
     headerName: 'First Salary', field: 'firstSalary', width: 130, 
},
```

Thank You.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472529/ag-grid-number-formatting-eg123456-78-to-123-457/41095123#41095123 @Kesty

Answer (score 2):

```
CurrencyCellRendererUSD(params: any) {
        var inrFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
          style: 'currency',
          currency: 'USD',
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        });
        return inrFormat.format(params.value);
      }

      columnDefs = [
        { headerName: 'A/c No', field: 'accountNo', width: 100 },
        { headerName: 'A/c Name', field: 'accountName' },
        { headerName: 'A/c Balance in USD', field: 'accountBalance', cellRenderer: this.CurrencyCellRendererUSD }
      ];

      rowData = [
        { accountNo: '1', accountName: 'Prajakta', accountBalance: 1000 },
        { accountNo: '2', accountName: 'Sanketa', accountBalance: 10000 },
        { accountNo: '3', accountName: 'Harsha', accountBalance: 100000 },
        { accountNo: '4', accountName: 'Janhavee', accountBalance: 1000000 },
        { accountNo: '5', accountName: 'Vignesh', accountBalance: 10000000 },
        { accountNo: '6', accountName: 'Upesh', accountBalance: 100000000 }
      ];
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOd5M.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the filter to `currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'`.

This modifies the filter to use a dot as the decimal separator and use 2 digits after the dot.

The documentation at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/index.php shows you how to define a column. You already specified the `field` paramter, now you must also add the `filter` parameter, and then it seems that the `template` is no longer necessary.

Comment: thanx but it showing syntax errors ag-gird is not supporting i think @RoyDictus

Comment: BTW, why are you still using RC4? It's quite an old version. Version 2.1.0 is out already.

Comment: Yes, but due to some reasons we are not updating the project
can u please resolve these issue with RC4.

Comment: i have updated the version of my project is there any other way for Us currency format like 2,300,200 like these. @Roy Dictus

Comment: Why would there need to be another way? Can't you use a filter as proposed?

Comment: I'm sure you understand that, in order for people to help you further, we're going to need a bit more information than that...