# jQuery number counter doesn't accept commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently creating a number counter (from 0 to a value) and I am having some trouble with getting the number to render if it's separated by a comma.

I have found some potential fixes such as toLocaleString but I can't get it to work - could anyone point me in the right direction?

Currently when I use 130,000 it returns NaN.

Thanks!

```js
$('.panel-text-style-c').each(function() {

  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toString());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='panel-text-style-c'>130,000</span>
```

The following above

Comment: Use `replace(',', '')` to remove the comma first.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thank you for the reply - where would I implement this? Sorry just a bit confused - thanks again!

Comment: I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JS, a `,` is not valid for use in a value to be parsed to an integer. This is why you receive the `NaN` output.

To fix this use `replace()` to remove the comma before providing it to the `Counter` property:

```js
$('.panel-text-style-c').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text().replace(/,/g, '')
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='panel-text-style-c'>130,000</span>
```

Comment: After implementing this, the comma doesn't get added in again, is this possible?

Comment: You could use `toLocaleString()` in the display logic. I've updated the answer to show you how. Note that if you want to force the comma grouping regardless of locale, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits)

Comment: Works a treat, thank you very much buddy!!! Will mark as the correct answer once it allows me to!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
$('.panel-text-style-c').each(function() {
  var num =   $(this).text().replace(',', '');
  
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: num
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toString());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='panel-text-style-c'>130,000</span>
```