# How to put comma seperator to a decimal number

Tags: javascript

I am stuck at one point,like how can i put a comma separator to a decimal number which are fixed to two decimals

example: 50506.2569 to 50,506.25

what i am doing is

```js
var variable = 32568.595;
var fix = variable.toFixed(2)
var seperator = fix.toLocaleString('en-in')
console.log(seperator);
```

this one is giving me `32568.60` but i am trying to get 32,568.60

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript

Comment: @brk i am doing that same,but no comma separator for decimal numbers

Comment: @viveksingh simple do with without `tofixed()` https://jsfiddle.net/r4mLxvnh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(format(32568.595));
console.log(format(32568));
console.log(format(32568.595, 0));


function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
 const fixed = number.toFixed(decimals);
 const [int, dec] = fixed.split('.')
 const intFormatted = (+int).toLocaleString(locale)

 return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}
```

Comment: this gives me `32,568.6` i want two decimals

Comment: @viveksingh check out my answer again :)

Answer (score 0):

This will format your numbers the way you want

```js
function formatNumber(amount) {
  const options = {
    style: 'decimal',
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  }
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', options)
  return formatter.format(amount)
}

console.log(formatNumber(50506.2569))
```

Comment: it is giving all the numbers after decimal i want to restrict it to 2

Comment: It's restricting it to two using this option `maximumFractionDigits: 2`
you can just run the snippet and check

Comment: You can learn more about different options [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Comment: let me try once

Answer (score 0):

```
var variable = 32568.595;
variable = +variable.toFixed(2); // Limit to 2 numbers after comma
variable = variable.toLocaleString(); // Make separator ','
```

This should work

Comment: it is giving only one decimal